# Square POS api for Cordova/PhoneGap applications

Tags: android, ios, cordova, square-connect

I'm thinking to use square POS api in my application to process all my customer's payments. Currently, its a web based mobile app but very soon we will be converting it to PhoneGap/Cordova native ios/andriod app. I could see there is web based mobile api support for square POS charge.

Do you have anything similar for Phonegap/Cordova apps? Please let me know. Ours is a huge customer base, so we will have to make a decision whether to go with square or not?

Answer (score 1):

Square does not have an official library for PhoneGap/Cordova, but these mobile frameworks can be used to build Square payment solutions on both iOS and Android. You should use the NATIVE SDKs to initiate/receive POS API requests, as opposed to the web API. The web API is only intended for browser-initiated requests.

Your application would need to implement the native callback mechanism in PhoneGap/Cordova (URL Schemes for iOS and/or Intents for Android), so that the response is sent back to the native PhoneGap/Cordova application.